# what's the difference between the two Pick<T,K> util type implementations

Tags: typescript

I'm trying this:
https://github.com/type-challenges/type-challenges/blob/master/questions/4-easy-pick/README.md

I can't understand the difference between them:

```
type MyPick<T, K> = T extends {} ? K extends keyof T ? {[P in K]: T[P]} : never : never

type MyPick<T extends {}, K extends keyof T> = {[P in K]: T[P]};
```

you can play it at:
[enter link description here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PQKgUABBAsELQQAoEsDGBrS8491gRgJ4QCCAdgC4AWA9mcQGICuEAFAAICGlAZkwJQQAxAFNOAZ2JCmZZHWH4myADYU4yMlixCdEAIpMR4inM1QsASQC2AB2UirIyhGoiIilWo0QABigwAPAAqADQQANIAfD4QAOZOIgBOaBAA7sjUNEwUEEziGrEQGQB0WlAAwnTGiUyoFOIQnC6ENm5EEDZo6AUuVG7iIjk0PB2JNK2JJka%204TE8Y1a%20QT5lEAw0iRAiAB6ctvarPkf1WBoUSTycqG5BNAAmNBAA3lhQJhT2AFwQ1QWvEHcjKhkjYTHRvr8yLF-qgaPtBiI7t98DQaPZuFgAL6rCgtG73GiIRIiABuyBEqQgAF4IABZQj%20dDBAlhADk73srIgAB8IKzYfDzndWZFVrCyMYXATvrcHkTSeTKTSXlBVS4Ml8%20eV0WQIGM4ayQv8oAK7AikRBLsoBkaoNioEcVuYoJEIAA1RUQeQAcQyAAkmPhvlQKBQbOJPsBgPVUFRigArcTFDaxYDQMAgYBgbOgCAAfQLhaLhYgAE0sptKoCIH6km5iw2CxBM9nca06QyusEwlFqRAglttucyHcGk9MRAAPwRQfD0cQdAiQjDftT54AbUQRV14QAujLN7uJ98yKSkhAT2fEjngM12-TGcFZ055%20Oe8%20Rw1F8uRkFXcrN23CJ937Q9MQAbmzMBc0bBt%20yMHJygkaZYOLZss2QWwNhyJ4IAAUQARyYThlDCPDtlaOoIAneY4T5dg2xEOBYxI%20woSMYBshUcRWVbPEIFQZCGhpdcsHIyiKACQjiOUKSKJEOpEQARjCB8u1lGg2Q5EQRUiSJbXw%20S6ikoiSLkiTEQAJlUztAg0rSNR0nk%20VNewhV0-SsCjCAGPEOAdgk-zEjGa8oDUuyWT5bSuV5fk4TNdznNZDQSRI5BhU83dszOC4rnxB5niwbSIQoZIoSwQFxGBZBQVMEqyuhE14rcxFkVRHUwGxMAcsSS5rkMiy7iUwq3kc%20q-i6nq%20rccSFKFSyRvVD4RHG8qmsFVr3HasRNC6nMQHzVCS2YSY%20k2ABlc5w0Oo683Q6DwBdCBzqoThiQgZcmE2cQ0S4qpg1DcNI2jKq40TZNElTaBgG4cRUiSLBXQ9Ckfl%20sEJQBsMIyjGMwaTFM02AH7lD%20iVEbpDY3HKV7lDY%20IIwgEMseB3GE3xyGMyzMAgA)

test case:

```
type A = {name: string; value: number;}
type B = MyPick1<A, 'name' | 'value'> // got {name: string} | {value: number}
type C = MyPick2<A, 'name' | 'value'> // got {name: string; value: number;}
```

I'm confusing at the results, and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First `MyPick`:

```js
type MyPick<T, K> = T extends {} ? K extends keyof T ? {[P in K]: T[P]} : never : never
```

Can accept any two generic types. I mean, you can call it with `MyPick<1,2> // never` or `MyPick<[], false> // never`, which of course does not make sense but still allowed because constraints are checked inside the body of the utility.

---

Second `MyPick`:

```js
type MyPick<T extends {}, K extends keyof T> = {[P in K]: T[P]};
```

This `MyPick` has a constraints for both arguments. FIrst argument should extend `{}` which is practically `any` type an second argument should be a key of first argument.

For example:

```js
type Test0 = MyPick1<2, 'toString'> // ok
type Test1 = MyPick1<2, 3> // expected error
```

As you might have noticsd, you still allowed to pass first argument as a primitive type because every value in JS is an object, hence has its own keys.

```js
// "toString" | "toFixed" | "toExponential" | "toPrecision" | "valueOf" | "toLocaleString"
type NumberKeys = keyof number;
```

I assume you want to apply a constraint where user only allowed to pass an object as a first argument, it means that you should use `Record<PropertyKey, any>` constraint. For Example:

```js
type Test0 = MyPick1<{ age: number }, 'age'> // ok
type Test1 = MyPick1<2, 'toString'> // error
type Test2 = MyPick1<true, 3> // expected error
```

---

> Why MyPick1 returns a Union type ?

See this:

```js
// Slightly reduced
type MyPick1<T, K> = K extends keyof T ? { [P in K]: T[P] } : never

type A = { name: string; value: number; }

type B = MyPick1<A, 'name' | 'value'> // got {name: string} | {value: number}
```

`MyPick1` returns a union because of [distributivity](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types). Please read thoroughly this section of the docs. This is very important feature.

`K` union type distributes, it means that this line `{ [P in K]: T[P] }` is applied to each union.

See another one example, to make it more clear:

```js
type Distibutive<T> = T extends any ? T[] : never

type Result1 = Distibutive<'a' | 'b'> // "a"[] | "b"[]

// This is how you disable distributivity
type NonDistibutive<T> = [T] extends [any] ? T[] : never

type Result2 = NonDistibutive<'a' | 'b'> // ("a" | "b")[]
```

Comment: I'why MyPick1 returns a Union type?

Comment: @IHAVEAQUESTION made an update